# Joomla embeddeds JS/CC files

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, compression

I recently came across the fact that Joomla delivers pages where CSS/JS files are compressed and embedded in the main document like here: [Demo Site](http://www.svenbluege.de/demo2/)

My question is: How can one turn this behavior off?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking to have the js uncompressed or if you don't want to load js.  You don't have to use the core template, most people don't, you can make your own or get one from one of the thousands of templaters out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... that's what happens if you use your phone tethered to your computer. The mobile providers seems to do a lot of modification to the delivered content. I just had access to a non mobile internet connection where this behavior not occurs.

**Because of this there is of cause not option to turn this off for Joomla.**

But in the end this makes our life as developers harder since those compressors might not be free of issues and our code stops randomly working for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A Joomla extension can either use the framework or inject manually the code for scripts and css: so if you use $document->addScriptDeclaration the code will be injected in the template (jdoc include head); otherwise if the programmer just output a < script > tag in the markup, it will be in the main extension's markup when the template is rendered.

So the solution is to open each individual extension, find the scripts/styles, remove them and insert all the code into a separate file (custom.js and custom.css typically)